# Grails trying to find tomcat:2.3.11 even though ":tomcat:7.0.54" is in BuildConfig

Tags: grails

I'm working on upgrading an app to Grails 2.3.11 and when I try to build it, Grails tries to download  org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.3.11/tomcat-2.3.11.pom, which, of course, is not found, so the build fails.  I have build ":tomcat:7.0.54" in the plugin section of BuildConfig and I don't have the tomcat plugin referenced anywhere else.  I've tried cleaning, I even wiped out my .grails directory in a moment of desperation.

Why would it continue to try to download the ${grailsVersion} version instead of the one explicitly declared?

Comment: Make sure there isn't a second dependency expressed in BuildConfig that is trying to pull in :tomcat:${grailsVersion}.  If that doesn't work try doing a `grails clean` and cleaning local caches.  Maybe an old version of your BuildConfig.groovy is being found somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Jeff!  It was a plugin that I was loading locally with plugin.location because I'm off the client's network.  The plugin is built with 2.2.4 so changing it, temporarily, to tomcat:2.2.4 solved the problem.